# Convert CSV to Nested JSON complex structure using Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested, jupyter-notebook

Converted into a nested JSON file using Pandas

This is the sample csv for one row

```
name      type  aitm      alitm     aaitm           adsc1   
specs     glass 70072187  ESA65Z45  ESA 65Z45       CUT TIP FG 1808-40
```

I'm trying to achieve the below structure of Nested JSON for every row

Comment: What does pandas have to do with this?

Comment: Pandas is one of the python package which makes importing and analyzing data much easier.

Comment: I think the comment really meant to say is this question isn’t really a pandas related question. Other than just a simple reading in a csv, pandas is not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame([['specs','glass','70072187','ESA65Z45','ESA 65Z45','CUT TIP FG 1808-40'],
                   ['specs','glass','666','ESA6665','ESB 666','CUT TIP FG 66-40']],
                       columns = ['name', 'type','aitm','alitm','aaitm','adsc1' ])


data = {'entities':[]}
for key,grp in df.groupby('name'):
    for idx, row in grp.iterrows():
        temp_dict_alpha = {'name':key, 'type':row['type'], 'data':{'attributes':{}}}

        attr_row = row[~row.index.isin(['name','type'])]
        for idx2, row2 in attr_row.iteritems():
            dict_temp = {}
            dict_temp[idx2] = {'values':[]}
            dict_temp[idx2]['values'].append({'value':row2,'source':'internal','locale':'en_US'})

            temp_dict_alpha['data']['attributes'].update(dict_temp)

        data['entities'].append(temp_dict_alpha)


print(json.dumps(data, indent= 4))
```

**Output:**

```
print(json.dumps(data, indent= 4))
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "name": "specs",
            "type": "glass",
            "data": {
                "attributes": {
                    "aitm": {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "70072187",
                                "source": "internal",
                                "locale": "en_US"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "alitm": {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "ESA65Z45",
                                "source": "internal",
                                "locale": "en_US"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "aaitm": {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "ESA 65Z45",
                                "source": "internal",
                                "locale": "en_US"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "adsc1": {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "CUT TIP FG 1808-40",
                                "source": "internal",
                                "locale": "en_US"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "specs",
            "type": "glass",
            "data": {
                "attributes": {
                    "aitm": {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "666",
                                "source": "internal",
                                "locale": "en_US"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "alitm": {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "ESA6665",
                                "source": "internal",
                                "locale": "en_US"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "aaitm": {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "ESB 666",
                                "source": "internal",
                                "locale": "en_US"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "adsc1": {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "CUT TIP FG 66-40",
                                "source": "internal",
                                "locale": "en_US"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I’ll take a look tomorrow morning and get back to you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want a separate json file for each unique value for `aitm`? I guess then my question would be why wouldn't you group by that rather than by 'name'? or why is that value so far down your level? I do have to say, this json format is inefficient as well (just as a note) as there are lots of repeats and there are lists of 1 value/dictionaries too which is unnecessary (unless there more to this than the data you provided as an example.)

Comment: ya that can easily be done. you'll just iterate through each row. i'll post a solution shortly

Comment: @satyaveni, Should be a simple solution. Can't do it right now, but I will be able to fix this shortly.

Comment: @satyaveni, ok I put the solution in the question/link you provided